# PHP Looping through a forms text fields only

Tags: php

Suppose I have a form like this:

```
echo "<form action='form_rec.php' method='post'>";

//These fields are dynamically generated du5, du6 etc...
echo '<input type="text" name="du1" value="125"><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="du2" value="326"><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="du3" value="090"><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="du4" value="425"><br>';

echo "<input type='hidden' name='input' value='key'>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='button' name='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

how can I loop through only the `type="text"` fields using php. The output i'm trying to achieve is:

```
du1 125
du2 326
du3 090
du4 425
```

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){
    echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

but this outputs the hidden key as well as the submit button's values

```
du1 125
du2 326
du3 090
du4 425
input key
submit submit
```

How can i get only the `type="text"` fields name and value?

Comment: You can't distinguish `input`s by type. Only by names, so change names somehow and check `$key` value.

Answer (score 2):

You can either prepend a *specifier string* to text input fields before submitting form e.g. `text-125`, `text-090`... or use an array:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="du[]" value="125"><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="du[]" value="326"><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="du[]" value="090"><br>';
echo '<input type="text" name="du[]" value="425"><br>';
```

Otherwise there should be a condition using e.g. `preg_match()`:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('~^du\d*$~', $key))
        echo "{$key} {$value}<br>";
}
```

Comment: Maybe then just `foreach($_POST['du'] as $value)`?

Comment: Yes, that's the second approach. Choosing one all depends as I'm not sure what OP means clearly when they say *these fields are dynamically generated...*

Comment: @revo I meant there could be one or three or even ten, depending on what the users chooses.

Comment: @Norman If you can easily change the keys the array way would be the better choice here.

Comment: @revo the name holds the dispenser unit (du) and the values get input by the user which are the total sales per du on that day.

Comment: Is it possible to loop through all form elements except the last two. The last two will always be a type hidden, and a submit button...

Comment: @Norman The last approach in this answer provides a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Because all the text input names have a common substring ('du'), you can use **strpos** to check if this substring exists or not, i.e. if $key has the substring 'du' it refers to input text otherwise not.

Try this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){
    $myString = 'du'; //the substring common to all the text elements (du1,du2,du3,du4)
    if (strpos($key, $myString) === 0){ //strpos finds the position of a substring in a string ('du' position is at offset zero)
        echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

In this case, strpos will returns zero for input $key (because zero is the offset of the substring 'du') and will returns FALSE for hidden input $key and submit input $key (because the substring 'du' is not present).

This solution allows you not to change inputs name.

Please note the use of **===**,
using == will not exclude the FALSE results for either hidden input and submit input
infact FALSE == 0 will return TRUE

check this note from the **[PHP: strpos manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)**:

> Warning
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.